# Pathfinder Cavalier Order of the Tome and Scribe Scroll

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Looking at the Order of the Tome for Cavalier, they gain the ability "[Powerful Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/orders/paizo---cavalier-orders/order-of-the-tome)."  This ability allows a Cavalier to cast divine or arcane spells from scrolls as if they were a divine or arcane caster with a caster level of their cavalier level -4.  So an 8th level Cavalier can cast any 2nd level or lower spell from an arcane spellcaster spell list.

This leads me to looking for ways to make the Cavalier more self-sufficient rather than relying on purchasing scrolls at market or having a fellow caster scribe scrolls for him.  As near as I can tell, scribe-scroll is a nonstarter because even though I will have a caster level 4 at level 8, I don't have any spells "known."  This means I cannot craft scrolls, as scrolls are spell completion items and you can't bypass the spell prerequisite on spell completion items.

But what if I took a single level of Wizard?  This grants me access to a spellbook and spells "known."  If I pay to have someone scribe a second level spell into my spellbook, can I then craft the scroll (since it is a "spell known" without having the ability to cast the spell as a wizard, or is there a rule I'm missing that disallows this?

If that won't work, is there another way a Cavalier could scribe scrolls for himself taking advantage of his full caster range with a small dip or specific feat selection? (up to 8th level scrolls at 20th level)

Comment: Note that you couldn't even *take* Scribe Scroll with only Cavalier levels, since the ability does not actually *give* you a caster level. It only allows you to act as if you *had* one for the purpose of doing a specific thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you may not.**

[Per the PFSRD section on Creating Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls):

> The creator **must have prepared the spell to be scribed** (or must know the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any material component or focus the spell requires. A material component is consumed when she begins writing, but a focus is not. (A focus used in scribing a scroll can be reused.) The act of writing triggers the prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting until the character has rested and regained spells. (That is, that spell slot is expended from the caster's currently prepared spells, just as if it had been cast.)

If you aren't high enough level to cast it, you *know* it but can not *prepare* it. Therefore you can't make a scroll of it.

You can scribe a higher level spell into your spellbook (yourself, if you can make the Spellcraft check, you don't have to hire someone and could get it off a scroll in the first place), but that only gets you halfway there.

What you might do is just take the wonderful Leadership feat and get a lackey to scribe scrolls for you...

Comment: Does that feat that allows non-spellcasters to use a single magical item-creation feat allow Scribe Scroll? Even if it doesn't, it seems a reasonable thing to ask of the DM considering how this cavalier works.

Comment: @KRyan If you thinking of [Master Craftsman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman---final), it only allows Craft Magic Arms and Armor and Craft Wondrous Item, not Scribe scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  That makes sense.  I don't think my DM is going to let me take leadership though, considering how broken it can be.